# Mongoose skip and limit (MongoDB Pagination)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I am using skip and limit in mongodb mongoose it returns random documents.
Sometimes it returns same documents.

I am trying to get limit number of documents and after skip i want to get next limit documents.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to use the pagination concept here. In both SQL and NoSQL, the data must be sorted in a specific order to achieve pagination without jumbled data on each db call.

for example:

```
await Event.find({}).sort({"createdDate": 0}).skip(10).limit(10);
```

I'm trying to fetch the 10-20 data in the above case, which is sorted using createdDate. So, the data won't shuffled while fetching, unless you insert or delete the data.

I hope this answers your question